# µs-precision wait in C for linux that does not put program to sleep?

Tags: c, sensors, raspberry-pi3

I'd really like to implement a 25µs delay in a C program I am writing to read a sensor via an RPi 3. I've employed nanosleep() and usleep(), but the accuracy seems a bit off -- likely because the program cedes thread time to other programs, then must wait for them to finish. I run with 'nice -n -20' to ensure priority, but it still seems a bit less accurate than I'd like. I've also tried a for loop, but can't quite nail down the clock-tick:for-loop-count ratio required to get 25 µs (I'm very new to all this)... or maybe gcc is optimizing the empty loop into oblivion?

At any rate, might someone be able to point me in the direction of a microDelay() function or something like this? (I've spent hours googling and experimenting, but can't quite seem to find what I'm looking for). Thanks!

Comment: basically this is not possible in a multitasking environment.  find another way.

Comment: It's also going to depend on what Linux distribution (and therefore kernel) that you're using. Hard real-time constraints on delay values on the order that you specified are difficult to achieve on large OSes like Linux. You may need to use a special kernel configured for real-time operation, or even an RTOS, depending on how strict your requirements are.

Comment: perhaps you can use the USART SPI or I2C interface to communicate with that sensor.

Comment: @Jasen, "not possible" isn't quite accurate -- real-time operating systems have been a source of profit for commercial embedded OS vendors long past the point when Linux took over the general market.

Comment: Check if your kernel is compiled with hrtimer and dyntick support. If so, and if you use a realtime-priority process, a 25µs sleep should reliably wake up on time (plus some overhead, maybe).

Comment: If you do want to use a spin loop, don't use a fixed number of iterations. Instead repeatedly call `clock_gettime` until the desired time is reached.

Comment: "not possible" for someone of the skill level demonstrated,

Comment: Have you looked at [`clock_nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html) and related functions? Have you looked at the [`timer_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html) and related functions, or their obsolescent predecessors 
[`getitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html) etc?  You can still run into scheduling delays.  You can investigate [`sched_setscheduler()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_setscheduler.html) etc.

Comment: @Jansen you are assuming. The thing might be different, because this is a very specific feature that not all programmers will ever need to implement, so I think you are confused with the terms used, maybe instead of "*skill level*" you meant "*knowledge*", and even though any of the two are easily extended with some effort, so if you think you thought too quickly, just admit that.

Comment: What worked for me (on an Arduino) is usage of inline assembly. Depending on the architecture, you can disable all interrupts via op code and then increment a counter in asm. This might not work on Linux system but it sure increases the granularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achieving this low resolutions (less than 1ms) is almost impossible in conventional multitasking operating systems without hardware support, but there is a software technique which could help you. (I've tested it before)

Software delay loop isn't accurate solution because of processes preemption by operating system's scheduler. But you can patch your kernel with RT_PREEMPT and enable it via CONFIG_RT_PREEMPT, now you have a kernel with realtime scheduling support, the realtime kernel let you run a process with realtime priority, the process with realtime priority run until it wants nobody could preempt it, so if you run a delay loop the process will not preempted by operating system so you could created accurate delays with these loops.

Comment: There is no need to patch the kernel for this, use `sched_setscheduler` with `SCHED_FIFO` and maximum priority. man 7 sched

Comment: @Ctx Without patching kernel to RT, kernel threads such as disk or irq handlers could preempt userspace tasks, but with SCHED_FIFO with CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT enabled, nobody could preempt userspace rt task, even kernel itself

Answer (score 0):

There was a point in Linux 2.something where nanosleep had a specific behavior for processes scheduled under a real-time policy like SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR where it would busy-wait when the specified sleep was below the minimum clock resolution or granularity, but it was removed. (Try man nanosleep, I believe this behavior is mentioned there).

I had a need to have a more precise sleep interval so I wrote my own version to call in those special cases. On the target machine I was able to get < 10 µs delays with only occasional blips (see the comment in the code).

Just remember that for non-real-time scheduling policies, if your application tries to sleep for less than the minimum clock resolution, it may still be preempted.

Here is a little test program that I wrote to test this, the busy loop calls clock_gettime() so it knows when it's time to wake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <signal.h>


void usage(char *name, const char *msg)
{
    if ( msg )
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s, -s<sleepNanoseconds> [-c<loopCount>] [-e]\n", name);
    fprintf(stderr,"  -s<sleepNanoseconds> is the number nanoseconds to busy-sleep, usually < 60000\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"  -c<loopCount> the number of loops to execute the busy sleep, default 1000000 \n");
    fprintf(stderr,"  -e do not calculate min, max and avg. only elapsed time \n");
}



# define tscmp(a, b, CMP)                             \
  (((a)->tv_sec == (b)->tv_sec) ?                         \
   ((a)->tv_nsec CMP (b)->tv_nsec) :                          \
   ((a)->tv_sec CMP (b)->tv_sec))
# define tsadd(a, b, result)                              \
  do {                                        \
    (result)->tv_sec = (a)->tv_sec + (b)->tv_sec;                 \
    (result)->tv_nsec = (a)->tv_nsec + (b)->tv_nsec;                  \
    if ((result)->tv_nsec >= 1000000000)                          \
      {                                       \
    ++(result)->tv_sec;                           \
    (result)->tv_nsec -= 1000000000;                          \
      }                                       \
  } while (0)
# define tssub(a, b, result)                              \
  do {                                        \
    (result)->tv_sec = (a)->tv_sec - (b)->tv_sec;                 \
    (result)->tv_nsec = (a)->tv_nsec - (b)->tv_nsec;                  \
    if ((result)->tv_nsec < 0) {                          \
      --(result)->tv_sec;                             \
      (result)->tv_nsec += 1000000000;                        \
    }                                         \
  } while (0)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// busySleep uses clock_gettime and a elapsed time check to provide delays
/// for less than the minimum sleep resolution (~58 microseconds). As tested
/// on a XEON E5-1603, a sleep of 0 yields a delay of >= 375 Nsec, 1-360 about
/// 736 Nsec, 370-720 a little more than 1 Usec, 720-1080 a little less than
/// 1.5 Usec and generally it's pretty linear for delays of 10 Usec on up in
/// increments of 10 Usec, e.g., 10 Usec =~ 10.4, 20 Usec =~ 20.4 and so on.
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int busySleep( uint32_t nanoseconds )
{
    struct timespec now;
    struct timespec then;
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec sleep;
    if ( nanoseconds > 999999999 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    now = start;
    sleep.tv_sec = 0;
    sleep.tv_nsec = nanoseconds;
    tsadd( &start, &sleep, &then );
    while ( tscmp( &now, &then, < )  )
    {
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &now);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint32_t sleepNsecs = 1000000000;
    uint32_t loopCount = 1000000;
    bool elapsedOnly = false;
    uint32_t found = 0;
    int opt;
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        sleepNsecs = atol(argv[1]);
        usage( argv[0], "Required options were not given" );
        return 1;
    }
    while ( (opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:d:e")) != -1 )
    {
        switch ( opt )
        {
        case 's':
            sleepNsecs = strtoul(optarg,NULL,0);
            break;
        case 'd':
            loopCount = strtoul(optarg,NULL,0);
            break;
        case 'e':
            elapsedOnly = true;
            break;
        default:
            usage(argv[0],"Error: unrecognized option\n");

            return 1;
        }
        found++;
    }
    if ( found < 1 )
    {
        usage( argv[0], "Invalid command line." );
        return 1;
    }
    if ( sleepNsecs > 999999999 )
    {
        usage( argv[0], "Sleep nanoseconds must be less than one second." );
        return 1;
    }

    printf("sleepNsecs set to %d\n",sleepNsecs);
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec now;
    struct timespec prev;
    struct timespec elapsed;
    struct timespec trem;

    uint64_t count = 0;
    int64_t sum = 0;
    int64_t min = 99999999;
    int64_t max = 0;

    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    now = start;
    prev = start;
    //while ( tscmp( &now, &then, < )  )
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++ )
    {
        int rc = busySleep( sleepNsecs );
        if ( rc != 0 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "busySleep returned an error!\n" );
            return 1;
        }
        if ( ! elapsedOnly )
        {
            clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &now);
            tssub( &now, &prev, &trem );
            min = ( min < trem.tv_nsec ? min : trem.tv_nsec );
            max = ( max > trem.tv_nsec ? max : trem.tv_nsec );
            count++;
            sum += trem.tv_nsec;
            prev = now;
        }
    }

    if ( ! elapsedOnly )
    {
        printf("Min: %lu, Max: %lu, avg %lu, count %lu\n",min,max,(sum / count),count);
    }
    else
    {
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &now);
        tssub( &now, &start, &elapsed );
        double secs = ((double)elapsed.tv_sec) + ((double) elapsed.tv_nsec / (double)1e9 );
        fprintf( stderr, "Elapsed time of %ld.%09ld for %u sleeps of duration %u, avg. = %.9f Ns\n",
                 elapsed.tv_sec, elapsed.tv_nsec, loopCount, sleepNsecs, (secs / loopCount) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```